# What is the preferred design pattern to delay rendering of a component in React?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, reactjs, rendering

I'm currently defering rendering of a component by initializing a state `readyToRender` to false and setting it to true once I have the data needed to render the UI.

My render function looks something like:

```
if (this.state.readyToRender) {
  return (
    // render component
)} else {
  return false; // don't render component
}
```

Is this the correct pattern to utilize for this problem or is there a better way to solve this?
Related questions:

- [Delayed rendering of React components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803440/delayed-rendering-of-react-components)
- [React delayed rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33097064/react-delayed-rendering)

Comment: is your data in props?

Comment: This logic is perfectly fine.

Comment: My data is currently stored in `this.state` but the design could of course also be re-done so that I pass down the data as props.

Comment: Even if your data is in state, try to compute the readyToRender out of the existing data, and not by creating another boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we try to derive the "loaded" state from the data, instead of holding it in `this.state`. While data is not available, we show a spinner, but you might as well show nothing.

So for example:

```
const TextShower = (props) => {
  if (props.text) {
    return <div>{props.text}</div>
   }

   return <img src='https://s31.postimg.org/g3992fx7v/477.gif' />
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/omerts/8r3dh6hw/

We have also created a high-order component for taking care of this (loader image changed so the example works):

```
const loaderComponent = (ComposedComponent, predicate) => {
  return (props) => {
    const isLoading = predicate && predicate(props)

    if (isLoading) {      
      return <div className='loading-data'>
                <img src='https://s32.postimg.org/8w18tbrlx/477_1.gif' />
             </div>
    }

    return <ComposedComponent {...props} />
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
const TextShower = (props) => { 
  return <div>{props.text}</div>   
}

const LoaderTextShower = loaderComponent(TextShower, 
                                         (props) => !props.text)
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/omerts/4edgbhmz/

From the "Thinking in React" doc:

> Can you compute it based on any other state or props in your component? If so, it's not state.

Comment: Thanks, I'll construct my UI in this tiered fashion by passing props down instead of setting from state. I'll mark this answer as accepted if it gets more votes or otherwise gets the consensus of the community of being the preferred way to solve this problem.